# React Native is taking forever to create a new app

Tags: macos, react-native

I am not new to React Native, had used it a lot 8-10 months back. Was working on Ubuntu way back then, and had gotten things to work fine.

Now, I am trying to run the same on MAC. It is taking too much time(5mins+) to create the app.
Is there anything I am missing? Any config which can speed up the process?

Terminal Output:

```
bozzmob-mac:reactnative bozzmob$ react-native init firstApp
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/bozzmob/collection/work/github/reactnative/firstApp
Installing react-native package from npm...
^C
bozzmob-mac:reactnative bozzmob$ cd firstApp/
bozzmob-mac:firstApp bozzmob$ ls
node_modules    package.json
bozzmob-mac:firstApp bozzmob$ cd ..
bozzmob-mac:reactnative bozzmob$ rm -rf firstApp/
bozzmob-mac:reactnative bozzmob$ react-native init AwesomeRNApp
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/bozzmob/collection/work/github/reactnative/AwesomeRNApp
Installing react-native package from npm...
```

Using

- node v6.2.1
- react-native-cli: 1.0.0
- react-native: 0.33.0

OS details-

```
bozzmob-mac:AwesomeRNApp bozzmob$ uname -a
Darwin bozzmob-mac 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Mon Aug 29 20:21:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

React native project takes much time to create project. Create project with this command

```
react-native init MyAwesomeProject --verbose
```

Comment: please explain that how will it help in reducing the time ?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you execute *init* the necessary node packages are downloaded into the node-modules folder. So depending on your connection it can take time.